# dispatch_barrier_async equivalent in Swift 3

Tags: concurrency, swift3

Refactoring a colleague's code, and I'm looking for the equivalent of `dispatch_barrier_async` in swift 3. There are a lot of queues at play, and his design is to block only this queue, and only for this single operation.

```
// Swift 2.3
func subscribe(subscriber: DaoDelegate) {
  dispatch_barrier_async(self.subscribers.q) { // NOTE: barrier, requires exclusive access for write
    //...
  }
}

// Swift 3 
func subscribe(subscriber: DaoDelegate) {
  (self.subscribers.q).async { // (Not equivalent, no barrier on the concurrent queue)
    //...
  }
}
```

Can I keep that same functionality in Swift 3 without refactoring all the queue types?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `async()` method has a `flags` parameter which accepts a `.barrier`
option:

```
func subscribe(subscriber: DaoDelegate) {
  (self.subscribers.q).async(flags: .barrier) { 
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Just got the same answer from `swift-users` mailing list.